# How can protect or encrypt my Swift Package?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I can make a Swift Package and use it like every one does, when I add my private or public url of my github and i import my package, I can see the source code that I used and the codes are exposed to me or to anyone that imported my Swift Package, I want to know what steps should I take to protect my source code? for example I have a package called: **CustomText** how can I let me or other using the package with this condition that they cannot see the source code of it or even hiding it and also encrypt it as well? thanks

Comment: Distribute it as compiled binary, not as a source code.

Comment: In case you didn't know, each sentence starts with a capital letter and ends with the period in English.

Answer (score 1):

To distribute code in binary form as a Swift package, create an XCFramework bundle, or artifact, that contains the binaries. Then, make the bundle available locally or on a server:

- When you host the binaries on a server, create a ZIP archive with the XCFramework in its root directory and make it available publicly.
- If the XCFramework is available locally and included in the package’s Git repository, you don’t need to create a compressed archive and can reference the XCFramework directly.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/distributing_binary_frameworks_as_swift_packages

Comment: @user If you aren't going to distribute the source, you need to provide a binary. What other way were you thinking of?